# Am I in a virtual network, or not logging in to my gateway?

Tags: router, gateway

When I do a LAN Scan, my gateway address is completly different than the address I use to log in to my router. Is this normal?

I have factory reset my router, and no change. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.
Thanks in advance

When I run a scan to get my network info I see

1. My external IP is one thing (which I haven’t been able to change in years) and starts with `174.172.x.x`.
2. My default gateway is one thing and starts with `100.115.x.x`.

When I log in to my router I used the IP address that the manufacturer tells me to use that starts with `192.168.x.x`

I am very sorry if I am just ignorant to this. It just looks very weird.

Comment: Please edit your question: Can you share what the gateway is — in some way that doesn’t expose it — here so we can all see what you might see. I am assuming your LAN scan is showing an internal IP address versus the external IP address? Or something else.

Comment: When you say starts with `19`, do you mean `192`? Are you using your own router and a separate modem from your ISP? Or is it a combination router/modem from your ISP?

Comment: LAN scan will not show your external IP. If you need help, please explain everything you are doing. Including how you run LAN scan, how you are connecting to the router etc. BTW It is safe to share any IP that starts with 10.x.x.x; 172.16.x.x; 192.168.x.x.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 yes, I mean 192.168.0.1 is how I access my Netgear Modem Router combo.I have no ISP equipment.

Comment: @RomanK I am using a Chromebook connected via Wi-Fi to run the app Net Anayllizer. On the general "Network Information page is where i see my external IP address.  When I do the LAN Scan I see Default Gateway IP 100.115.92.13 .

Comment: Van you check your question and ensure the first part of each IP address is correct to the "." - From a technical POV there are very significant differences between 17. And 172, likewise for 10. And 100. And 19. And 192.  - its also helpful of you included the first 2 whole octets - 192.168 is very different to 192.1 - and likewise for 100. And 172.

Comment: @davidgo I appologize. I will edit the question- It should have been 172.174  and 100.115 and 1928.168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all looks correct (although the use of carrier grade NAT is less then ideal) and virtual networks do not apply.

I expect the bit you are missing is that you are behind Carrier Grade NAT.  Carrier Grade NAT works like regular NAT except at an ISP level, and often using the IP range set aside for it - ie `100.64.x.x` to `100.127.x.x`

Thus what is most likely happening is :

Your LAN is using `192.168.x.x`, and your WAN port is assigned `100.115.x.x`. Your ISP has grouped your external IP address with others and uses Carrier grade NAT to enable wider internet access via `174.172.x.x`  - This means that when you go to a site like `whatismyip.com` it says your IP address is `174.172.x.x`.

Comment: Thank you! This probably explains why I have a few other issues. I appreaciate the knowledge, and your time.

Comment: Rereading your comment on my deleted post - if you are paying any kind if premium for a business account you are likely being "done over" by your ISP - I would expect a business account to, at minimum - not be behind CGN.